# CSS inline-block list grid

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have a list of items that I'd like to display in a grid-like way. And I want each item to have a custom width, based on its content plus the padding around it. So I just added the appropriate styles, and added a display of inline-block to each li. But the issue is that I want the grid to be square to the edge of its container. So I want the last list item on each line to expand to fill the width remaining on that line. How can I go about this?

[image]

Here's a fiddle of what I've got: http://jsfiddle.net/Lk0e028c/

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>lorem</li>
    <li>ipsum</li>
    <li>dolor</li>
    <li>sit</li>
    <li>amet</li>
    <li>consectetur</li>
    <li>adipiscing</li>
    <li>elit</li>
    <li>Vestibulum</li>
    <li>porttitor</li>
    <li>nisi</li>
    <li>purus</li>
    <li>eu</li>
    <li>pretium</li>
    <li>ipsum</li>
    <li>ultricies</li>
    <li>eu</li>
    <li>Nulla</li>
    <li>eleifend</li>
    <li>arcu</li>
    <li>dolor</li>
    <li>et</li>
    <li>vestibulum</li>
    <li>ligula</li>
    <li>lacinia</li>
    <li>sed</li>
    <li>Sed</li>
    <li>viverra</li>
    <li>tortor</li>
    <li>lorem</li>
    <li>molestie</li>
    <li>volutpat</li>
    <li>nisi</li>
    <li>volutpat</li>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>Suspendisse</li>
    <li>dolor</li>
    <li>lacus</li>
    <li>ultrices</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0;
    width: 300px;
}

ul li {
    background: #ccc;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 15px;
    margin-left: -3px;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
}

ul li:hover {
    background: #ddd;
}
```

Comment: When deciding for the "best answer", keep in mind that it should probably be the one that best fullfills the requirements you made. If you still have difficulty at any given point of the explanation, feel free to ask!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use flexbox:

```
ul {
  display: flex; /* Magic begins */
  flex-wrap: wrap; /* Multiline */
}
ul li {
  flex-grow: 1; /* Grow to fill available space */
}
```

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  width: 300px;
}
ul li {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-right: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  text-align: center;
}
ul li:hover {
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>lorem</li>
    <li>ipsum</li>
    <li>dolor</li>
    <li>sit</li>
    <li>amet</li>
    <li>consectetur</li>
    <li>adipiscing</li>
    <li>elit</li>
    <li>Vestibulum</li>
    <li>porttitor</li>
    <li>nisi</li>
    <li>purus</li>
    <li>eu</li>
    <li>pretium</li>
    <li>ipsum</li>
    <li>ultricies</li>
    <li>eu</li>
    <li>Nulla</li>
    <li>eleifend</li>
    <li>arcu</li>
    <li>dolor</li>
    <li>et</li>
    <li>vestibulum</li>
    <li>ligula</li>
    <li>lacinia</li>
    <li>sed</li>
    <li>Sed</li>
    <li>viverra</li>
    <li>tortor</li>
    <li>lorem</li>
    <li>molestie</li>
    <li>volutpat</li>
    <li>nisi</li>
    <li>volutpat</li>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>Suspendisse</li>
    <li>dolor</li>
    <li>lacus</li>
    <li>ultrices</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Even though I like the approach, this again is not what the OP asked for: He wants the **last item** in *each line* to **fill the rest of the line** visually. *" I want each item to have a custom width, based on its content plus the padding around it"*

Comment: I guess I thought that's what I wanted because I thought that was all that was possible @connexo. This works quite nicely.

Comment: Well, in that case I could have saved half an hour of my life probably. :( Next time, better state directly what you ideally want without making clueless assumptions as of what might be (im)possible to achieve. Sorry, but this annoys me since my solution is clearly much closer to what you defined as requirements. Feels like getting punished for walking the extra mile when there was an easy way to achieve something further away from your specs in less than a minute.

Answer (score 1):

This is about as close as I can get it in two minutes:

## What I offer

[image]

```css
ul {
    background: #ccc url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAAxCAYAAAAbb8MkAAAABmJLR0QA/wD/AP+gvaeTAAAACXBIWXMAAAsTAAALEwEAmpwYAAAAB3RJTUUH3wUbER07M8cXywAAAB1pVFh0Q29tbWVudAAAAAAAQ3JlYXRlZCB3aXRoIEdJTVBkLmUHAAAAGklEQVQI12M4c+bMfyYGBgaGkUEw/P///z8AbfkHvv+4euUAAAAASUVORK5CYII=') repeat 0 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 300px;
    font-size: 0;
}

ul li {
    border-width: 0 0 1px 1px;
    border-color: #fff;
    border-style: solid;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 1rem;
}

ul li:hover {
    background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>lorem</li>
 <li>ipsum</li>
 <li>dolor</li>
 <li>sit</li>
 <li>amet</li>
 <li>consectetur</li>
 <li>adipiscing</li>
 <li>elit</li>
 <li>Vestibulum</li>
 <li>porttitor</li>
 <li>nisi</li>
 <li>purus</li>
 <li>eu</li>
 <li>pretium</li>
 <li>ipsum</li>
 <li>ultricies</li>
 <li>eu</li>
 <li>Nulla</li>
 <li>eleifend</li>
 <li>arcu</li>
 <li>dolor</li>
 <li>et</li>
 <li>vestibulum</li>
 <li>ligula</li>
 <li>lacinia</li>
 <li>sed</li>
 <li>Sed</li>
 <li>viverra</li>
 <li>tortor</li>
 <li>lorem</li>
 <li>molestie</li>
 <li>volutpat</li>
 <li>nisi</li>
 <li>volutpat</li>
 <li>a</li>
 <li>Suspendisse</li>
 <li>dolor</li>
 <li>lacus</li>
 <li>ultrices</li>
</ul>
```

> http://jsfiddle.net/Lk0e028c/3/

### Remaining problems

1. hovering the last item in each line reveals the way this visual effect has been faked and
2. if the last item is solo in its line, the background still stretches to the full with of the `<ul>`.

### How did I achieve this?

#### Step 1

I moved the background color away from the list items and to their parent ul:

```
ul { 
    background: #ccc;
    ...
}
```

#### Step 2

I gave the list items a 1px white border on the left and bottom:

```
ul li {
    border-width: 0 0 1px 1px;
    border-color: #fff;
    border-style: solid;
    ...
}
```

#### Step 3

Since the white line below each line of item will refuse to extend to the right end of the `<ul>` I have created a 1px wide background image and converted it to base64 so I can use it inline:

[image]

> http://www.base64-image.de/step-1.php

The image has **one** white pixel on the bottom. You cannot see it here since it obviously melts with SO's white background-color.

#### Step 4

Add this image as `url` to the `background` property of the `<ul>` and make it `repeat`, starting at `0 0`:

```
background: #ccc url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAAxCAYAAAAbb8MkAAAABmJLR0QA/wD/AP+gvaeTAAAACXBIWXMAAAsTAAALEwEAmpwYAAAAB3RJTUUH3wUbER07M8cXywAAAB1pVFh0Q29tbWVudAAAAAAAQ3JlYXRlZCB3aXRoIEdJTVBkLmUHAAAAGklEQVQI12M4c+bMfyYGBgaGkUEw/P///z8AbfkHvv+4euUAAAAASUVORK5CYII=') repeat 0 0;
```

### Done!

Comment: That does look not bad. But your solution totally just lost me

Comment: Re-check it, I included all you need to know in four easy steps.

Comment: This is the best CSS-only solution to exactly what I asked for, unfortunately the hover issue makes it a deal-breaker

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be really difficult to achieve the result with a CSS only solution.

I would look into a javascript solution to recompute block width and align them accordingly. It will also be really helpful to ensure responsiveness.

You may want to check [wookmark](http://www.wookmark.com/)

Comment: I guess you're right, that probably be the only way to achieve what I want

Answer (score -1):

A simple solution is define a width for the li's:

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0;
    width: 300px;
}

ul li {
    background: #ccc;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 15px;
    margin-left: -3px;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    width: 70px;
}

ul li:hover {
    background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>lorem</li>
 <li>ipsum</li>
 <li>dolor</li>
 <li>sit</li>
 <li>amet</li>
 <li>consectetur</li>
 <li>adipiscing</li>
 <li>elit</li>
 <li>Vestibulum</li>
 <li>porttitor</li>
 <li>nisi</li>
 <li>purus</li>
 <li>eu</li>
 <li>pretium</li>
 <li>ipsum</li>
 <li>ultricies</li>
 <li>eu</li>
 <li>Nulla</li>
 <li>eleifend</li>
 <li>arcu</li>
 <li>dolor</li>
 <li>et</li>
 <li>vestibulum</li>
 <li>ligula</li>
 <li>lacinia</li>
 <li>sed</li>
 <li>Sed</li>
 <li>viverra</li>
 <li>tortor</li>
 <li>lorem</li>
 <li>molestie</li>
 <li>volutpat</li>
 <li>nisi</li>
 <li>volutpat</li>
 <li>a</li>
 <li>Suspendisse</li>
 <li>dolor</li>
 <li>lacus</li>
 <li>ultrices</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Well, this is nowhere near what the OP asked for.

Comment: _" I want each item to have a custom width, based on its content plus the padding around it"_